# Showing that two unknown random variables are both Gaussian, if their sum is Gaussian

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I'm currently studying probability theory and came across this exercise question that I'm struggling to find the answer to.

I've found many resources regarding showing that the sum of two normally distributed random variables is also normally distributed, but am struggling to find anything that goes the opposite way.

The specific problem is as follows:

> Let $Y = X_1 + X_2$, where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are unknown i.i.d. random variables. Show that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are Gaussian if $Y$ is Gaussian.

I'm fairly lost and am having trouble on where to start. Any tips or advice are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to use characteristic functions, note that i.i.d.-ness of $X_1$ and $X_2$ implies
$$E[e^{itY}] = E[e^{itX_1} e^{itX_2}] = E[e^{itX_1}] E[e^{itX_1}] = E[e^{itX_1}]^2,$$
and then use the fact that $Y$ is Gaussian to conclude that $X_1$ is Gaussian.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the anwer. Sorry, but I'm still slightly lost. If it's not too much trouble on your part, could you please elaborate a bit more? Thanks again.

Comment: @Seankala Are you familiar with [characteristic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory))?

Comment: To be complete frank, I'm not that familiar with characeristic functions. However, reading up on them and reading your answer again, I'm assuming that due to the fact that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are i.i.d., they come from the same distribution. If $Y$ is normally distributed and its CF is equal to that of $X_1$, then $X_1$ is also normally distributed and so is $X_2$, as they are i.i.d. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Seankala The work in my answer shows that the CF of $Y$ is the square of the CF of $X_1$. Since you know $Y$ is normal (with some mean and variance), you can look up what the CF of $Y$ is, and then obtain the CF of $X_1$, and recognize that it is the CF of a different normal distribution.